# how to initialize list of string from linq select query?

Tags: c#, linq

I am initializing a list of strings from the code below:

```
            var headerValues = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
            {
                {
                    "section1",
                    new List<string>()
                    {
                        "id",
                        "item"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "section2",
                    new List<string>()
                    {
                        "titile",
                        "content1",
                        "content2"
                    }
                },
                // and the rest of sections
            };
            var results = from s1 in section1Collection
                          from s2 in section2Collection
                          from s3 in section3Collection
                          from s4 in section4Collection
                          select new List<string>
                          {
                              // section1
                              GetValue(s1, headerValues["section1"][0]),
                              GetValue(s1, headerValues["section1"][1]),
                              // section2
                              GetValue(s2, headerValues["section2"][0]),
                              GetValue(s2, headerValues["section2"][1]),
                              GetValue(s2, headerValues["section2"][2]),
                              // and the rest of sections
                          };
```

But there must be a way to do it in a loop, right? Or maybe initialize the results list in a function?

How do I produce this result list in a smarter, more reliable and more readable way?

BTW, the GetValue method just lookup the value in the s1, s2, etc from the passed in header value string.

Edit: what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
var results = from s1 in section1
              from s2 in section2
              from s3 in section3
              from s4 in section4
              select new List<string>
              {
                  // GetValues should return all section1 strings based on the headerValues["section1"] array
                  GetValues(s1, headerValues["section1"]),
                  // section2
                  GetValues(s2, headerValues["section2"]),
                  // and the rest of sections
               };
```

Comment: You can use `SelectMany` which will flatten each sublist. Not sure what you're asking exactly aside from that

Comment: You say you want a *list of string*, however what you have a list of well... nothing, this wouldn't compile... and even if it could, it would be a *list of object* with properties, you need to explain your output better

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned before what you are looking for is SelectMany. It flattens nested collections into one-dimensional one. Here is how you should use it.

```
var results = headerValues.SelectMany(item => item.Value);
```

so what it does? 'item' here is a KeyValuePair(since Dictionary which you use consists of them), and the item.Value is a list(because it is the type of this particular dictionary's value). Now given list of lists SelectMany joins them and return as a single IEnumerable of strings